# Sed remove between two specific characters failed

Tags: bash, sed

I have at `foo.txt`

If I do `cat get.txt` I have following

```
SCALARS md.100 int
```

I want to remove `.100` between `md` and `int`, and have output as

```
SCALARS md int
```

How I can  change it?

I have tried `sed "s/md.*int //g" get.txt`

which doesn't change anything.I got this as output

```
SCALARS md.100 int
```

Does anyone can explain why its not working and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: There is no space after `int`.

Comment: @melpomene ok, in fact I don't want to remove `int`. I just want to remove `.100`. it starts from `md` and end at `int`

Comment: `sed 's/md\..* int/md int/' get.txt`?

Comment: @Cyrus That works. Could you post it and I accept your answer, would be nice if you could explain what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/md\..* int/md int/' get.txt
```

It replaces `md.`, any characters (`.*`) and `int` (with leading space) with `md int`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Your sed expression is matching more than what you desire.  Also, if you want to write to a different file, you need to provide your file to parse, and pipe the output to another file.  The following should work:

```
sed -e 's/\.100//g' foo.txt > bar.txt
```

Will remove the ".100" and write to the new edited file "bar.txt", leaving "foo.txt" unchanged.